# Google App Engine app.yaml secret manager

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to make the secret manager work but without success.

I've made the "App Engine default service account" to be a "Editor and Secret Manager Secret Accessor".

I've put this piece of code in the app.yaml

env_variables:
DB_PWD: "projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET_NAME/versions/latest"

By the error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'cloudsqlproxy~13.103.249.118' (using password: YES)" this clearly isn't replacing the password.

What other configuration i'm missing for the secret replacement?

Thank you in advance to whoever knows what may be missing

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a client to get the secrets from secret manager.  For example, in Python:

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
MY_SECRET = client.access_secret_version('projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET_NAME/versions/latest')
```

You can't put the secret in an environment variable in app.yaml.

Comment: Thank you for replying, so this needs to be done at code level instead of environment level? I'm using PHP.